# How to count the Framerate with which a SurfaceView refreshes?

Tags: android, surfaceview

I have a third party framework that shows video on a [SurfaceView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html). I would like to measure the framerate of the video to check if the phone is capable of showing the video fast enough, or if I need to use another solution to show the information to the user.

How can I measure the speed with that a SurfaceView is updated?

Comment: This answer might help.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13498184/editing-android-videoview-frames/13667582  Override the draw method..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If the code is not clear just ask.

```
LinkedList<Long> times = new LinkedList<Long>(){{
    add(System.nanoTime());
}};

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    double fps = fps();
    // ...
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}

private final int MAX_SIZE = 100;
private final double NANOS = 1000000000.0;

/** Calculates and returns frames per second */
private double fps() {
    long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
    double difference = (lastTime - times.getFirst()) / NANOS;
    times.addLast(lastTime);
    int size = times.size();
    if (size > MAX_SIZE) {
        times.removeFirst();
    }
    return difference > 0 ? times.size() / difference : 0.0;
}
```

Comment: It's good only for drawing canvas and not useful for i.e. when rendering via mediacodec

Answer (score 5):

try this!

```
private long mLastTime = 0;
private int fps = 0, ifps = 0;
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();

    // perform other operations

    System.out.println("FPS:" + fps);

    ifps++;
    if(now > (mLastTime + 1000)) {
        mLastTime = now;
        fps = ifps;
    ifps = 0;
    }
}
```