# Editing android VideoView frames

Tags: android, android-videoview, android-source, android-4.2-jelly-bean, motion-detection

## Environment:

**Nexus 7 Jelly Bean 4.1.2**

## Problem:

I'm trying to make a Motion Detection application that works with RTSP using VideoView.

I wish that there was something like an onNewFrameListener

```
videoView.onNewFrame(Frame frame)
```

I've tried  to get access to the raw frames of an RTSP stream via VideoView but couldn't find any support for that in the Android SDK.

I found out that VideoView encapsulates the Android's MediaPlayer class.

So i dived into the `media_jni` lib to try and find a way to access the raw frames, But couldn't find the byte buffer or whatever that represents a frame.

## Question:

Anyone has an idea where or how can i find this buffer and get access to it ?

Or any other idea of implementing a Motion Detection over a VideoView ?

**Even if it's sais that i need to recompile the AOSP.**

Comment: Does your app target on Android 4.1 and up only?

Comment: Yes, but if i need an earlier version i can manage that too.

Answer (score 3):

You can extend the `VideoView` and override its `draw(Canvas canvas)` method.

- Set your bitmap to the canvas received through `draw`.
- Call `super.draw()` which will get the frame drawn onto your bitmap.
- Access the frame pixels from the bitmap.

  ```
  class MotionDetectorVideoView extends VideoView {
  public Bitmap mFrameBitmap;
  ...
      @Override
      public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
          // set your own member bitmap to canvas..
          canvas.setBitmap(mFrameBitmap);
          super.draw(canvas);
          // do whatever you want with mFrameBitmap. It now contains the frame.
          ...
          // Allocate `buffer` big enough to hold the whole frame.
          mFrameBitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer);
          ...
      }
  }
  ```

I don't know whether this will work. Avoid doing heavy calculation in `draw`, start a thread there.

Comment: How can i get raw pixels of the drawn canvas ? couldn't find anything in their API about it.

Comment: There is `public void copyPixelsToBuffer (Buffer dst)` in Bitmap class. documentation here : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#copyPixelsToBuffer(java.nio.Buffer)

Comment: Yes, but how to get the Bitmap from the Canvas?

Comment: You already have the bitmap reference in `mFrameBitmap`.. Create the bitmap in constructor.. See the edit above..

Comment: So you say that when i call `super.draw(canvas)` it draws on the current bitmap and not replacing with a new one ?
And I'm able to call NDK calculation inside `draw` ?

Comment: Haven't you tried it yet? Im not sure about that. Can do NDK calc if it doesnt slow down or flicker the video..

Comment: Tried it.. `onDraw` doesn't even get called.

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing"?

Comment: I'm on debug mode, breakpoint inside the `public void draw(Canvas canvas)` with `@Override` before, and the debugger doesn't get there..

Comment: Doesn't work ...
Set Bitmap is a not supported operation for Video view... Because it's not a simple canvas , it's HardwareCanvas !

 java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
            at android.view.HardwareCanvas.setBitmap(HardwareCanvas.java:39)
            at com.zemingo.MyVideoView.dispatchDraw(MyVideoView.java:38)

Answer (score 1):

In your case I would use the Camera Preview instead the VideoView, if you are working with live motion, not recorded videos. You can use a Camera Preview Callback to catch everyframe captured by your camera. This callback implements :

```
onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera)
Called as preview frames are displayed.
```

Which I think it could be useful for you.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.PreviewCallback.html

Tell if that is what you are searching for.

Good luck.