# RTSP Player Live Stream Android App

Tags: android

I'm trying to develop an android app that allow streaming video from the IP Camera. I finally got the video from the IP camera to display on the app using videoview with mediacontroller but it seem to have some drawbacks. Please help me, thank you!

The functionalities that I need improve: 
1) Reduce the playback delay between the camera and video display on the app
2) Record live stream, allowing to view the playback 10 seconds before to 10 seconds after.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Please post the source code that you are using so that we can be of assistance.

Comment: Hello, my source code is based from this tutorial: http://www.androidbegin.com/download/VideoStreamTutorial.rar. Thanks.

Comment: @gariepy, do you have any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Some general suggestions...how many frames per second do you need?  One way to cut down on processing latency is reduce the number of frames.  Going from 24 frames/sec to 15 frames per second might help.  Depends on your application.  Is the latency noticeably greater than the native video recording latency?  Some phones have a perceptible delay with their built-in app, and you may not get better than that.

Comment: Thanks for the response, how do I reduce the number of frames? I use a tablet to display the video. Is there any other option than VideoView for rtsp streaming? and how do I allow record mode? Thanks @gariepy.

Comment: Not sure...I haven't used VideoView myself, but here's a discussion on how to extend it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13498184/editing-android-videoview-frames.  You could probably use this method to record also by saving the frames on the way to the display (using a separate thread so you don't introduce latency)

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more on how I can do that? Thank you, you have been very helpful.